# Handlebars Templating Engine Not Defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am working through *Web Development with Node & Express: Leveraging the JavaScript Stack*, by Ethan Brown.  I am working in chapter three, which introduces basic concepts concerning Express.  I created the app, *meadowlark.js*, as the book has said, and I am getting this error concerning the Handlebars Templating Engine:

`ReferenceError: handlebars is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/PROJECT_STORAGE/site/meadowlark.js:7:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3`

Here is the code for how I setup Handlebars and the rest of *meadowlark.js*:

```js
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

// setup handlebars view engine
var handlbars = require('express-handlebars').create({ defaultLayout: 'main' });
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.render('home');
});

app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
 res.type('about');
});

// custom 404 pg
app.use(function(req, res) {
 res.status(404);
 res.render('404');
});

// custom 500 pg
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
 //console.error(err.stack);
 res.status(500);
 res.render('500');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
 console.log('Express started on localhost:' + app.get('port') + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
});
```

How can I fix my code to make Handlebars initialize correctly and make *handlebars.js* run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo `var handlbars = require('express-handlebars').create({ defaultLayout: 'main' });`

should be `var handlebars`.

Pro tip: Use a linter in your ide.